Callable Bond Delta Profile
I am analyzing a callable bond with 10 Years of maturity coupon paid monthly at market rate plus the spread of 25 bps. The bond has an American Call option embedded. The strike price of a bond option is set at 5%. I would like to know the delta profile of a bond, I have observed that the delta shoots up around the 4.60% level which seems unusual as I am expecting it to be around 5% or 4.95%. Can you please help me to get the delta profile of these bond?
Thanks
